# avoid dir mod rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

i have a rule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^posts/(.*)/([0-9]*)$ viewupdates.php?username=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

and match to: http://site.com/posts/username/1

i need to chante to:

```
http://site.com/username/posts
```

without trailing slash, and if have more pages /posts/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply transpose the corresponding parts of the regexp for the latter case:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/posts/([0-9]*)$ viewupdates.php?username=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

Probably, you also want another rule without the extra "page" specification (for the former case you describe), smth like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/posts$ viewupdates.php?username=$1 [L]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/posts$ viewupdates.php?username=$1&page=1 [L]
```

depending on your implementation of the script.

Comment: Good. It's a very primitive question & answer.

Try to think more, and understand the code that you read, use and write! There'd be no such question if you did.

Also try to express your thoughts and questions in English in a more clear way (I had much more troubles understanding what you meant than composing the answer), and write with less orthographic and grammatical errors! Just stop for a while before posting, please, and re-read your text, and ask yourself please: "Is my text understandable?"